# Synchronized threads throwing a CurrentModificationException

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I am having trouble getting the concurrency running on a simple UDP chat client I am writing, it all works perfectly until I try to add a new contact to the outgoing message list stored in Peer, it throws a CurrentModificationException, can someone help me understand where I have gone wrong?

Here are my classes

```
    import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Chatter {

   public static class ReceiveMess extends Thread{ 

   DatagramSocket ds;   
   public ReceiveMess(DatagramSocket s){
        ds = s;
    } 

     byte[] Rbuf = new byte[1000];
     DatagramPacket Rdgp = new DatagramPacket(Rbuf, Rbuf.length); 

        public synchronized void run() {
            try{
                while (true){
                    for(Peer p : Peer.PeerList){
                        ds.receive(Rdgp);
                        String rcvd = new String(Rdgp.getData(), 0, Rdgp.getLength()) + ", from address: "
                        + Rdgp.getAddress() + ", port: " + Rdgp.getPort();
                        System.out.println(rcvd);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class SendMess extends Thread{

    DatagramSocket ds;  

    public SendMess(DatagramSocket s){
            ds = s;
    }


    int SPORT = 40080;
    byte[] Sbuf = new byte[1000];
    DatagramPacket Sdgp = new DatagramPacket(Sbuf, Sbuf.length);

        public synchronized void run() {
            try{
                while (true) {
                    BufferedReader consR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    String MessOut = consR.readLine();
                    if(MessOut.startsWith("/NEW")){
                        try{
                            String[] splitArray = MessOut.split(" ");
                            String newIP = (splitArray[1]);
                            Peer p = new Peer(newIP);
                            System.out.println(newIP + " added to the contacts list");
                            continue;
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            System.out.println("Please format NEW IP address's as NEW XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        Sbuf = ("Server Said: " + MessOut).getBytes();
                        for(Peer p : Peer.PeerList){
                            DatagramPacket out = new DatagramPacket(Sbuf, Sbuf.length, p.IP, SPORT);
                        ds.send(out);}
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){

      try{  
        for(String s : args){
            String address = s;
            Peer peer = new Peer(address);
        }

      int PORT = 40080;
      DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(PORT);

      Peer.PrintList();    

        SendMess sendmess = new SendMess(ds);
        sendmess.start();        
        ReceiveMess receivemess = new ReceiveMess(ds);
        receivemess.start();  
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    }
}

And my peer class,

        import java.net.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Peer{



        InetAddress IP;
        static List<Peer> PeerList = new LinkedList<Peer>();

        Peer(String clientAddress){ 
            try{
                IP = IP.getByName(clientAddress);
                AddToList(this);
            }
            catch(UnknownHostException e){
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }   

        public synchronized void AddToList(Peer peer){
            PeerList.add(this);
        }

        public List<Peer> GetList(){
            return PeerList;
        }

        public static void PrintList(){
            for(Peer p : PeerList){
            System.out.println(p.IP.toString());
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: In which line of your code you get the Exception? please add the stacktrace

Comment: You need to synchronize on a shared object, otherwise it doesn't really do anything. It is considered bad practice to extends Thread and using synchronized in it is a good way to see some tricky puzzlers ;)

Comment: I receive the error on line 27 which is the for each loop in ReceiveMess, I understand the error is iterating through the list while another thread is doing the same but I cannot fix it

Comment: Actually since the two sychronized blocks are designed to run at the same time and both are an infinite loop, using a shared object for the lock would cause deadlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your issue is this...

You have a loop in `ReceiveMess` that iterates the list in `Peer`. At the same time in `SendMess` you are creating new instances of `Peer`. When a new instance of `Peer` is created this adds a new element to the `PeerList`. This then causes the CME in `ReceiveMess`.

What I would suggest is that you remove all the `synchronized` keywords as they are not doing anything for you and return a COPY of the list from `Peer.getList`. This means that as one thread is iterating the list, even if the other thread modifies the list of `Peers` the iterating thread will not be effected. The iterating thread will then see the update on the next iteration of the while loop.

One mechanism to do this is to use a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or Guava's `ImmutableList.Builder`.

[CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

[ImmutableList.Builder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `synchronized` for a method is equivalent to:

```
public void run() {
    synchronized(this) {
     ...
    }
}
```

In your synchronized methods, `this` is a different object (`ReceiveMess`,`SendMess` and `Peer`), so there's nothing stopping those methods from running at the same time. Use a common monitor instead, (`Chatter.class` is the most expedient).

In other words, `synchronized` for methods is not global, it's just a shortcut to synchronizing on the monitor of `this`. I encourage you to read at least [this entire track](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) before you continue.

Comment: I receive the error on line 27 which is the for each loop in ReceiveMess, I understand the error is iterating through the list while another thread is doing the same but I cannot fix it

Comment: @JamesLuxton : please read the linked articles and come back with an edit if you're still stuck.

Comment: Actually since the two sychronized blocks are designed to run at the same time and both are an infinite loop, using a shared object for the lock would cause deadlock

Comment: @JohnB : **how** will it cause a deadlock? One thread will obtain the lock and keep running while the other will not. **Starvation, yes**, deadlock, no. Also, I've deliberately addressed only the immediate problem and given the link, so that the OP has an opportunity to at least grasp the basics of concurrency.

Comment: Point taken, you are correct that it causes `starvation` instead of `deadlock`. Either way this will not help a concurrency newbie solve his/her issue.

Comment: @JohnB : I'd rather say that learning the basics of concurrency and reinforcing that knowledge by solving the subsequent problems encountered oneself is better help than presenting a full code analysis. But I suppose that's opinion based on whether you prefer the "give a fish" vs the "teach how to fish" approach.